# Change site titles in Sites web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I am building a Sharepoint Online site and have an issue with the Sites web part in a site collection hub.

I have a number of site collections which do not have the proper title. When I rename the site collection the title changes in the site, but does not change in the associated hub (the hub shows the title that I gave to the site on creation).

Here you can see the admin center site showing the three sites and their hub. The sites are all team sites and no communication sites.
[image: Admin view of the site collections and their hub.]

When we look in the hub we see the Sites web part. All three sites are shown with the titles Test1, Test2 and Test3. These titles I want to change.

[image: Sites web part in hub]

In the individual site collections I have changed the title, which can be seen here "Title that I want".
[image: The title I want in site collection]

Renaming the individual site names did not do the trick. I also tried to change the name of the associated O365 Group, but that also did not change the title of the sites displayed in the hub.

How can I change the titles of the site collections in the Sites web part?

Comment: Hello, have you tried removing and adding the sites web part back?

Comment: Yes. I've removed it and put it back. I also have a testing demo tenant (screenshots). There the problem is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested this and found the solution. First of all, you will have to remove the association with the hub site for the newly renamed sites. This can be done from the SharePoint online admin center. Then, associate the sites back with the same Hub site. This time the new title should show up.